# Detect prerender view in PHP?

Tags: php, http-headers

How can I detect a prerender page view in PHP?

When I use prerender it messes up my page view counter.

So maybe it would be possible to detect with some unique http header entry from the browser prerendering?

Answer (score 0):

If rendered page will be clear HTML, that in my opinion your only option is to use JavaScript to send AJAX request for counting your site view.

Comment: Sure, but then I lose all script block users etc ;)

Comment: That scripts blocks counting user? Ban ip?

Comment: I ment noscript, umatrix & co